# Run 2 instances of qbittorrent-nox on same linux

Tags: ubuntu, headless, bittorrent

I've been using qbittorrent-nox + WebUI on a headless server for a few months and it's working pretty good.

I'd like to separate a bunch of torrents I seed and that I keep active for months hoping for a seed to come back, from normal torrents that I download, seed for a while and delete.

Is it possible to make qBittorrent and WebUI run in 2 instances, each on their own ports and settings, so that I can better organize my torrents?

Comment: Have you tried 2 instances under 2 different users?

Comment: No. How would I setup them to run on startup pointing the proper user?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. Run the following under the user you want to run qbittorent-nox:

```
/usr/bin/qbittorrent-nox --configuration=user1 -d --webui-port=8001
sleep 1
rm /tmp/qtsingleapp-qBitto-*
/usr/bin/qbittorrent-nox --configuration=user2 -d --webui-port=8002
```

There are three things here:

- You should configure different WebUI ports for each user;
- You should configure different configuration subdirectories for each user;
- Before starting a new instance you should delete the lock file created by previous instance. QBittorrent uses this to find its instances, and would otherwise refuse to start a new instance telling you that "qbittorrent is already running"

sleep 1 lets the first instance run a bit and create the lock file (which you then remove).

Answer (score 0):

I run my two qbittorrent instances from /etc/rc.local, which contains the following:

> run_nox() {
>
> > ```
> >   local WEBUI_PORT=$1
> >   [ ! -e /tmp/$WEBUI_PORT ] && mkdir /tmp/$WEBUI_PORT && \
> >   env -i HOME=/home/ubuntu USER=ubuntu TMPDIR=/tmp/$WEBUI_PORT \
> >   /usr/bin/qbittorrent-nox --configuration=$WEBUI_PORT --webui-port=$WEBUI_PORT -d
> > ```
>
> }

run_nox 8080

run_nox 8081

I have been running this on a Raspberry Pi 4B (64bit) Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) for some weeks now without any major issues.